# android outofmemoryerror bytearrayoutputstream

Tags: android, out-of-memory, bytearrayoutputstream

Halo guys, i want to download a long string which is from sql php,
and store as "result" in getHttpRespose() method,

and using this "result" to change into rows of data and add into android database,
but some low model android phone result in [outofmemoryerror bytearrayoutputstream] error,
so how can i modify my code to fix this?

thanks for all kindly help!

```
private static String getHttpResponse() {
    String result = "";
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(API_URL);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        Log.i("HTTP STATUS", ":" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

            Log.i("HTTP STATUS 200", "CONNECTION SUCCESS");
            result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            jsonString = result;

        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public static void addRecord(){
    createTable();

    InsertHelper ih = new InsertHelper(db, TABLE_CONTACTS);
    db.setLockingEnabled(false);
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jarray = jobject.getJSONArray("result");
        int tempCategory = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject oneObject = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            ih.prepareForInsert();
            // Add the data for each column
            ih.bind(1, checkNull(oneObject, "storeID"));
            ih.bind(2, checkNull(oneObject, "tradeID"));
            ih.bind(3, checkNull(oneObject, "hasBranch"));
            ih.bind(4, checkNull(oneObject, "districtID"));
            ih.bind(5, checkNull(oneObject, "categoryID"));
            ih.bind(6, checkNull(oneObject, "name_en"));
            ih.bind(7, checkNull(oneObject, "name_tc"));
            ih.bind(8, checkNull(oneObject, "name_sc"));
            ih.bind(9, checkNull(oneObject, "addr_en"));
            ih.bind(10, checkNull(oneObject, "addr_tc"));
            ih.bind(11, checkNull(oneObject, "addr_sc"));
            ih.bind(12, checkNull(oneObject, "short_addr"));
            ih.bind(13, checkNull(oneObject, "tel"));
            ih.bind(14, checkNull(oneObject, "lat"));
            ih.bind(15, checkNull(oneObject, "lng"));
            ih.bind(16, checkNull(oneObject, "logo_url"));
            ih.bind(17, checkNull(oneObject, "img_url"));
            ih.bind(18, checkNull(oneObject, "coupon_url"));
            ih.bind(19, checkNull(oneObject, "sort_type"));
            ih.bind(20, checkNull(oneObject, "sort_order"));
            ih.bind(21, checkNull(oneObject, "sort_type_tc"));
            ih.bind(22, checkNull(oneObject, "sort_order_tc"));
            ih.bind(23, checkNull(oneObject, "sort_type_sc"));
            ih.bind(24, checkNull(oneObject, "sort_order_sc"));

            ih.execute();
            isSuccess=true;
            isFirst=true;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("errorJSON", "errorJSON");
    } finally {
        ih.close(); // See comment below from Stefan Anca
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();

    done = true;

}

11-03 19:24:23.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28258): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 19:24:23.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28258): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-03 19:24:23.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28258): at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
11-03 19:24:23.193: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28258): at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:218)
```

Comment: Stacktrace / logcat output might help getting an answer

Comment: added into the question:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:largeHeap="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml in order to request more memory from the Android's Virtual Machine.

Comment: thanks, i have try it and it works, BUT it only works with direct USB debug mode, when i export it as an apk and the apps still hand during this process....:(

Comment: @user989816 Are you testing it on Emulator or Device? If you are testing on Emulator rise the VM Heap while creating it. It only works on 3.0+ :)

Comment: there are 3 case, emulator(done), usbdebug-device(done),export apk-device(fail)

Comment: before i use "largeHeap", it fail as"no response"; after i use it, it handed there with no report or crash,just handed and no change on screen...